# snowflake SQL date conversion

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have following values in my date table

```
Jan 7, 2019
Jan 14, 2019
```

I am trying to convert the above date column using to_date in snowflake sql. I am getting the
following error:-

```
Can't parse 'Jan 7, 2019' as date with format 'Mon DD,YYYY'
```

Here's the code:-

```
to_date(Date,'Mon DD,YYYY') as Date
```

Comment: Did you try with a lowercase m 'mon DD, YYYY'?

Comment: Are your account /session using language different than English?

Comment: Please see the updated question - Is this because of   date values ?

Comment: What is the schema of the date table. Can you share

Comment: 'mon DD, YYYY' worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a space after `DD`. As in it should be `to_date(Date, 'Mon DD, YYYY') as Date`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it. How are you getting the date

[image: Snowflake image]